# The use of Corner reflector and beams to find the distance between moon and earth and light Divergence?

Tags: optics, reflection

I am about to start college and my knowledge regarding both beams and retroreflectors is close to nonexistent ,
but from what I read  a corner reflector is a device  that reflects waves  back to its source with minimum scattering and it consists of three mutually perpendicular, intersecting flat surfaces, which reflects waves directly towards the source, but translated.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

$\vec a=(x,y,z)$ = the incoming ray

The incoming ray is reflected three times, once by each surface, which results in a reversal of direction. the final vector has the same (x,y,z) components   but in the opposite direction   $\vec b=-\vec a=(-x,-y,-z)$
so When the ray reflects from the first side, say x, the ray's x component is reversed to -x while the y and z components are unchanged, Similarly, when reflected from side y,  y changes to -y while the x and z components are unchanged and same for the z

so I imagine the process being as follows the light beam travels to the corner reflector  on the moon at the speed of light and then reflects back traveling the same distance so  we know that the total distance/time = speed of light
and  the distance from moon to earth lets call it r  =${\text{total distance}/2}$
so we get.  $$r=\frac{\text{speed of light}*{time}}{2}$$

if there is a problem in my understanding until this point please correct me

as for the light beam I have a couple of questions  , as the the light moves away from a reflectorized light source, it spreads out and becomes less intense , from what I understood This is a result of the wave nature of light , Diffraction is the bending of waves around obstacles and the spreading of waves when they pass through small openings. As light waves propagate through space, they undergo diffraction, causing the light beam to spread out.

so since the light beam is spreading and energy is being lost(some of the light is scattering and some may not be covered by the retroreflector ) how can I find how much energy is being returned and what factors should I consider?

Comment: See [Laser Beams Reflected Between Earth and Moon Boost Science](https://www.nasa.gov/missions/laser-beams-reflected-between-earth-and-moon-boost-science/). The important diffraction in laser beams occurs inside the laser cavity. See [Gaussian Beams](https://www.rp-photonics.com/gaussian_beams.html)

Comment: The light is not diffracted in space.

Comment: @JEB i went and read more about the diffraction topic , does not a wave that has the wave length , emerging from a pair of narrow slits; , and  separation between the slits; , the distance from the center of an interference pattern produced by the light on a screen; and , the distance from the slits to a bright fringe in the pattern of order   has a double slit diffraction pattern? And here i read that it works in vacuum and space if i am wrong do correct me https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/problem-with-the-two-slit-experiment.632930/#

Comment: @lodo diffraction occurs at the slit, not during propagation. Hyguen's principle notwithstanding.

Comment: @JEB  i went and read about Hyguen’s principle as soon as i saw your comment , first i want to correct that i talked up on a double slit diffraction instead of a single slit , secondly diffraction happens at the slit not during propagation can you go into more details regarding that ,from what i read diffraction happens from when light passes through a slit until it hits a screen i assumed that the screen would be on the moon while the slit is on earth and then diffraction  occurs or is it not even possible to place a screen that far ?

Comment: @JEB  secondly i want to know if  there are factors that can cause light to diffract in space like temperature or atmospheric conditions and if yes are they usually controlled for such experiments (light beams used to find distance between moon and earth and such ), and is there any factors that can cause the light to lose energy coming back to earth what are they ? sorry for the amount of questions its just that my knowledge in the topic is too shallow and i want to try to understand to the best of my ability and thx for your time and knowledge

Comment: And if there are too many questions in here at the comment section should i open a new post discussing only the topic of diffraction so that you can get credit for answering them ?